# I can't change the picture's width by using input range

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the html file:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("range");
let pic1 = document.getElementById("Pic1");
let pic2 = document.getElementById("Pic2");

element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    pic1.offsetWidth = `${element.value}%`;
}, false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="Script.js" async></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="Pic1" src="https://www.hzpc.com/uploads/overview-transparent-896/dc78aee8-3f50-5ba8-b8d3-6cf74852aa2b/3175818931/Colomba%20%282%29.png" alt="">
    <img id="Pic2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/potato-chips-260nw-116860495.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="range" name="" id="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is that whenever I move the slider, the first picture's width becomes the same value of the slider. But it's not working. Whenever I move the slider, nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `change` listener instead of `click` and set the width with css:

```js
element.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    pic1.style.width = `${e.target.value}%`;
})
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you!